# Vue router-view missing in tests

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I'm testing my vue code using Karma. When running the dev/building the production version it works properly, however when running the testing commands it doesn't work.

The versions I'm using:

"vue": "^2.4.2",

"@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",

"vue-router": "^2.7.0"

I've tried using Vue instead of Vue-test-utils mount to create the component but it creates more errors. I'm writing my test based on [these docs](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vue-router.html#writing-the-test)

**Test.spec.js**

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '@/components/Component'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/details/:id',
      name: 'Details',
      component: Component,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})


const vm = mount(App, {
    router: router,
    sync: false
  })
router.push('/details/2')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import './assets/app.css'
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

I expected VM to be the Vue Mounted app, however when logging it:

```
VueWrapper{isFunctionalComponent: undefined, _emitted: Object{}, _emittedByOrder: []}
```

And it gives the following vue warn:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

I have also kept the test running with webpack server, used my browser to have a look and notice that the `router.push` call does work, as it adds /details/2 to the URL.